# Error : CS5001 Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point WpfApplication

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

Yesterday I was switched one of my WPF projects to Class Library to make a NuGet package out of it. However, I forgot the change the App.xaml from being the ApplicationDefinition under properties and the project failed to build.

Without thinking the I double clicked on the error and the visual studio opened up a configuration file (don't remember its name) where there was a line defining application definition. I deleted that line and closed file. After that change, visual studio stopped building any of my WPF projects and started to spit out the "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method" error for all of them. All projects have the right settings and they used to build without a problem before I deleted this one line from a file. I suspect I edited a file that is not related to my project but is part of the visual studio configuration. Has anyone ever had anything like this?

I repaired visual studio 2017, installed 2019, and also tried to build my projects in 2015 but no luck. Even the brand new WPF projects throw the same error. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fix the build issues by uninstalling .net frameworks and reinstalling them.